# SQLite -> SQLite date formatting issues

Tags: sqlite, datetime, win-universal-app

I am working on migrating my old application data to a new application database. The old SQLite database has a `DateTime` column called `DateOpened`. When I look at the old data, I see this value: `2010-09-16 12:00:00`

When I query it in my new (UWP) application, the query returns `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM`, which I assume is because that is `DateTime.MinValue`.

The result in the new database, is a `DateOpened` value of `-62135510400`. Is this storing the value in ticks or something like that? Both SQLite databases have that column as a `DateTime` field, so I'm not really sure why they are being stored differently.

I updated a different row with the value `1/1/2007` from a `DatePicker` and it is stored in the new database as `1167694105.602`.

I don't necessarily mind that the new database stores the dates this way, but I am trying to figure out a way to get them to copy over properly. I tried manually setting the values in the new database, but with a normal date format (i.e. `1/1/2007`), the application crashes when trying to read from the database.

<strike>Can someone tell me what I'm missing here? It's probably something simple, but I'm stumped.</strike>

**EDIT**

I was able to get it to read the value correctly from the old database by specifying `storeDateTimeAsTicks = false`. The default value apparently is `true`, so my new database is storing as ticks, but when trying to read as ticks from string format, it wasn't working, so it would return `DateTime.MinValue`.

Comment: Good solution, I suggest you post it as a solution.

Comment: I was thinking I couldn't post an answer yet, but I just can't accept my own answer for 2 days. I have posted as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to read the value correctly from the old database by specifying `storeDateTimeAsTicks = false`. The default value apparently is true, so my new database is storing as ticks, but when trying to read as ticks from string format, it wasn't working, so it would return `DateTime.MinValue`.